# Xamarin.IOS / c# - Get NSObject values

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsobject

Is there a way to get the values from an NSObject?

I know we can do this `NSObject status = (NSObject)MyNSObject.ValueForKey(new NSString("myKey"));`

But what if I don't know the key?
Is it possible to get all values without supplying any one key?
Or is it at least possible to place a breakpoint on the NSObject and view the object's properties / key-value pairs in the visual studio IDE, the same that can be done for a c# object?

I ask as I have an NSObject but I don't know what the properties inside them are, as they aren't supplied to me.

Comment: Looking at [Apple doc for NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject), what you want is [attributeKeys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1415656-attributekeys). However, I don't see an equivalent in [Xamarin.iOS NSObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsobject?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12). Maybe I missed it, or maybe someone else knows more... There is a [Class property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsobject.class?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#foundation-nsobject-class). Find doc for that class.